# change browser's blue default color when selecting an option element in a select element

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I know how to change the color of the background of the options element, and also the hover.

What I'm trying to do is to change the default browser's color (blue in chrome) when you click over an option element, and while the "select" is still on focus.

I made this pen:

http://codepen.io/dieggger/pen/QbRZXP

-------------------------------HTML --------------------------------

```
<select size="3" name='options' multiple>
   <option value='option-1' class="options">Option 1</option>
   <option value='option-2' class="options">Option 2</option>
   <option value='option-3' class="options">Option 3</option>
</select>  

<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure suscipit 
   eos hic voluptatibus ratione impedit ullam sequi, delectus rem. Corporis nemo 
</p>
```

-------------------------------CSS---------------------------------------

```
select{
 border-radius:.5em;
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
}

::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; 
}

*:focus {
outline: #ffb7b7 solid 5px; 
}
```

I'd like to make the blue default color a #ffb7b7 like the outline and the text selection.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I played with your codepen and found this solution :

```
option:checked {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #ffb7b7 inset;
}
```

I added this code in your CSS.
It seems that box-shadow replaces the browser color so it works :) (tested on Firefox, Chrome 44)