# How to change default browser color in SELECT forms

Tags: css

I am developping a personal web site.
My theme is green based.

In a form with SELECT options, I would like that hover color is green and not default browser color (blue here). UI frameworks can change it but till now I have not found how to with css.

JP

[image]

## ---------------

I saw and tried the post but it does not concern when hovering the options:
[image]

```html
<select name='options' >
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

```css
select {
 border-radius:.5em;
 width:200px;
}
::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffb7b7;
}
*:focus {
  outline: #ffb7b7 solid 5px;
}
option:checked {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #ffb7b7 inset;
}
option:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
```

## ---------------

Strangely it works when using SELECT with "multiple" and when having in css the "option:hover". But this is not what I need :( ...

[image]

## ================

Well it seems it is impossible as in [Mozilla SELECT documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) there is an example with converting option to div by javascript to succeed.

I will use checkbox instead. Fortunately this time I have not so many options to display.

Comment: Please do not add answers that are not answers, but put the code that you tried related to the answer given in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099263/change-browsers-blue-default-color-when-selecting-an-option-element-in-a-select into your question, describing what the problem is as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example